# Is MongoDB exporting with strictly monotonically increasing IDs?

Tags: database, mongodb

If I use the `mongoexport` shell command to export documents from MongoDB, it normally returns documents starting at the lowest `_id` and then documents with a monotonically increasing `_id`.

If I do not apply any filters on the export, is the monotonically increasing `_id` of exports always guaranteed? Or does MongoDB just usually do it like this and something like fragmenting the DB or moving documents will interfere?

I use the standard `_id` values, so the IDs of an example export look like this:

```
ObjectId(5bc483da647c0a1ba98b1ac5)
ObjectId(5bc483da647c0a1ba98b1ac6)
ObjectId(5bc483da647c0a1ba98b1ac7)
ObjectId(5bc483da647c0a1ba98b1ac8)
ObjectId(5bc483da647c0a1ba98b1ac9)
ObjectId(5bc483da647c0a1ba98b1aca)
ObjectId(5bc483da647c0a1ba98b1acb)
ObjectId(5bc483da647c0a1ba98b1acc)  
ObjectId(5bc483da647c0a1ba98b1acd)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not prefer to depend upon MongoDB default filter ([Natural Order](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-natural-order)), rather use a custom filter to be guaranteed on output data.